# Rails devise does not send confirmation email but requires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I set up Devise and am able to create a profile.  When I create the profiles and try to log in, I get an error message that I have not confirmed my account,

I never got the email which I am supposed to confirm my own account.  Did I go wrong in selecting such an option, or not enabling Devise to email me?

Here is the migration I used to make it:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users, :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8') do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.confirmable
      t.encryptable
      t.column "first_name", :string  
      t.column "last_name", :string
      t.column "organization_name", :string

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Comment: What set-up have you used to handle your emails?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **development** mode, you have to add this line to `config/environments/development.rb`

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }`

Then, check your server logs to see the mail. You should find something like that:

> Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (19.5ms)
>
> Sent mail to example@mail.com (21951ms)
>
> Date: Thu, 26 May 2011 12:56:55 +0200
>
> From: sender@mail.com
>
> Reply-To: sender@mail.com
>
> To: example@mail.com
>
> Message-ID: <4dde31f7944bd_5ac277e0e4785c6@L-Portable.mail>
>
> Subject: Confirmation instructions
>
> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/html;
>
> charset=UTF-8

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<p>Welcome example@mail.com!</p>
<p>You can confirm your account through the link below:</p>
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Hi0tyRQU8cCFpAbatYFf">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

You also need to put this line in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.mailer_sender = "sender@mail.com"
```

If you **REALLY** don't have this mail in your logs, you can still validate your account by taking the value of `confirmation_token` in your DB and go to this link

```
http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token= #PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
```

And that should do the trick.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks!! for me FROM params was missing.